# Multiple textbox search on a datagrid

Tags: sql, vb.net

Okay struggling to get my head around the follow example. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.filterexpression.aspx)

Aim: To have two dropdowns/textboxes that are used to edit the datagrid filtering.

I have tried adding ,FirstName='{1}'" as well as ,FirstName='{0}'" after the =title but that is not seeming to work. I added a control parameter as well of course for FirstName.

The below code is first my version and then the original.

My Code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
            <head runat="server">
            <title>ASP.NET Example</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <form id="form1" runat="server">

                    <p>Show all employees with the following title:
                    <asp:DropDownList
                        id="DropDownList1"
                        runat="server"
                        AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">A</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>B</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList></p>

 <asp:DropDownList
                        id="DropDownList2"
                        runat="server"
                        AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">X</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Y</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Z</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList></p>

                    <asp:SqlDataSource
                        id="SqlDataSource1"
                        runat="server"
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Title FROM Employees"
                        FilterExpression="Title='{0}' or "FirstName='{1}'">
                        <FilterParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter Name="Title" ControlId="DropDownList1" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
 <asp:ControlParameter Name="FirstName" ControlId="DropDownList1" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
                        </FilterParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>

                    <p><asp:GridView
                        id="GridView1"
                        runat="server"
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <columns>
                            <asp:BoundField Visible="False" DataField="EmployeeID" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" DataField="FirstName" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name" DataField="LastName" />
                        </columns>
                    </asp:GridView></p>

                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: As I said I was sturggling to get my head around and had posted only the original code as I felt it was better to do that than my played with (and potentially misleading) code. Anyway help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally had a comma seperating the search queries. I actually needed to put 'or'.

See full code on original post (edited to be correct) and sample code below..

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource
                        id="SqlDataSource1"
                        runat="server"
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Title FROM Employees"
                        FilterExpression="Title='{0}' or "FirstName='{1}'">
```